# Creating object with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, object

First off, I'm using [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) for some DOM access and parsing with Node.js. Good times.

Heres the situation:

I have a function that I need to create an object. That object uses variables for both its keys and values, and then return that single object. Example:

```
stuff = function (thing, callback) {
  var inputs  = $('div.quantity > input').map(function(){
    var key   = this.attr('name')
     ,  value = this.attr('value');

     return { key : value }
  }) 

  callback(null, inputs);
}
```

It outputs this:

```
[ { key: '1' }, { key: '1' } ]
```

(`.map()` returns an array of objects fyi)

I need `key` to actually be the string from `this.attr('name')`.

Whats the best way to assign a string as a key in Javascript, considering what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you can get **dynamic object's key** with by: **myObj['key']**

Answer (score 1180, accepted):

In the new [ES2015 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) for JavaScript (formerly called ES6), objects can be created with *computed keys*: [Object Initializer spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer).

The syntax is:

```
var obj = {
  [myKey]: value,
}
```

If applied to the OP's scenario, it would turn into:

```
stuff = function (thing, callback) {
  var inputs  = $('div.quantity > input').map(function(){
    return {
      [this.attr('name')]: this.attr('value'),
    };
  }) 

  callback(null, inputs);
}
```

**Note:** A transpiler is still required for [browser compatiblity](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Using [Babel](https://babeljs.io) or [Google's traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), it is possible to [use this syntax today](http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#var%20key%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0A%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20%22blah%22%2C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aobj.foo).

---

In earlier JavaScript specifications (ES5 and below), the key in an object literal is always interpreted literally, as a string.

To use a "dynamic" key, you have to use [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
var obj = {};
obj[myKey] = value;
```

In your case:

```
stuff = function (thing, callback) {
  var inputs  = $('div.quantity > input').map(function(){
    var key   = this.attr('name')
     ,  value = this.attr('value')
     ,  ret   = {};

     ret[key] = value;
     return ret;
  }) 

  callback(null, inputs);
}
```

Comment: Great edit. Now if ES6 can just be officially released we might have a shot at world peace! :)

Comment: You can use Computed Property Keys now if you're willing to use a transpiler like Babel.  Example: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20NAME%20%3D%20'NAME'%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%7B%0A%20%20%5B'full'%20%2B%20NAME%5D%3A%20'Mike%20Smith'%0A%7D)%3B

Comment: Great update about *computed keys*. That's what I'm looking for these days. I just wonder how did you know about this "magic". Reading the (so long) ES2015 spec document?

Comment: For computed keys, I am getting a syntax error when using gulp minify task. Any body faced this? and any solution?

Comment: can this also work for nested Objects suppose i have a nested object can i use var obj ={ [dynamic key][dynamic key]=someValue }

Comment: Any solution for TypeScript?

Answer (score 73):

You can't define an object literal with a dynamic key. Do this :

```
var o = {};
o[key] = value;
return o;
```

There's no shortcut (edit: there's one now, with ES6, see the other answer).

Comment: I think in es6 you can now do this:

    var propname = 'thing'
    {[propname]:5} -> {thing:5}

See this for more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer