# Javascript variables in an object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to pass an object to another function but i have problems with global variables being referenced inside the object.

```
var a = 'first variable'; //SAMPLE GLOBAL VARIABLE
var b = 'second variable'; //SAMPLE GLOBAL VARIABLE

function iterator(options){
   for(var c in options){
    alert(c + ' ' + options[c]);    
   }
}

function main(){
   iterator({
      a:'5',
      b:'6'
   });
}
```

The functions should alert the output below

```
first variable 5
second variable 6
```

But instead I'm getting

```
a 5
b 6
```

I need to use variables inside the object.

Comment: Don't use local variable the same name as the global's it looks like you looking for troubles, there are tons of variables names that you can use.

Comment: yup updated but still doesn't work

Comment: @Kiel check my answer now. `alert(a + ' ' + options[c]); `

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: creating object with dynamic keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/javascript-creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your line `I need to use variables inside the object`, I suggest you rewrite your `main` as below:

```
function main(){
   var obj = {}
   obj[a] = '5';
   obj[b] = '6';   
   iterator(obj);
}
```

Since, `a` inside `for-in` loop will create new variable inside loop and refer to each key of object

Comment: This one works thank you. I might need to change alot of codes lol

Comment: Also for the question above here is the answer for the single js http://jsfiddle.net/nB5m3/2/ from @ling.s

Comment: @Kiel: This stackoverflow wouldn't be raised if you would have used different variable name inside for-in loop :). Since, you would have got what you wanted there itself. :) Anyway, Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `a` in the function is the local variable declared in the `for` loop.

```
var a = 'first variable'; //SAMPLE GLOBAL VARIABLE
var b = 'second variable'; //SAMPLE GLOBAL VARIABLE
var opts = {a: a, b: b};

function iterator(options){
   for(var a in options){
    alert(opts.a + ' ' + options[a]);    
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry but the global variable opts cannot be global because i would be passing the object to a javascript library. Sorry if i did not mention i thought it wasn't a factor.

Comment: Didn't work sorry. The two functions are actually separated to 2 javascript files. There will be lots of changes in the code to access the global variable opts from the other javascript file. But if I only have 1 file this works.

Comment: @ling.s sorry just look at my comment to your answer and thank you

Answer (score 1):

The a & b which you trying to access are tied to the Window object.

When you were printing 'a' or 'b' otherwise, it was printing the key 'a' from the Key/Value of you JSON.

```
$(window).load(function() {
main();
});
```

and,

```
function iterator(options){
   for(var a in options){
    alert(window[a] + ' ' + options[a]);    
   }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gauravmuk/NY72c/)

Comment: `window[a]` is undefined

Comment: have you defined var a = 'first variable'; like the example? this should work, i have tested myself.

Comment: and do this after window has loaded otherwise the variable might be undefined before the script actually executed.

Comment: you are using `$(window).load(function() {
    main();
});`, but you didn't mention this in your answer. Also you can link the fiddle in your answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the edit, the OP now changed the variable name, so now variable a can be directly accessed

```
function iterator(options){
 for(var c in options){
     alert(a + ' ' + options[c]);    
 }
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nB5m3/2/)

Comment: this works with one js file. I need the main function in a separate file that is why i cannot access the global variable a. I just made the js here simplier but the js file where the `function iterator` is present is actually inside a js library that i would access from the main javascript.

Comment: thanks and sorry if i didn't mention the js library.

Answer (score 0):

The `var a` here is specifically for creating a *new* variable with function scope that shadows the global variable:

```
function iterator(options){
   for(var a in options){
    alert(a + ' ' + options[a]);    
   }
}
```

You can't do that, if you still want to access the global...