# Javascript: Unable to create JSON object using String.fromCharCode for generating keys and values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to fix character mappings on paste within a text area element using the following object to match characters.

```
var replacementMap = {
    String.fromCharCode(61607) : String.fromCharCode("9632"),  //solid box
    String.fromCharCode(61623) : String.fromCharCode("9679"),  //solid circle
    String.fromCharCode(61656) : String.fromCharCode("9654"),  //right arrow
    String.fromCharCode(61692) : String.fromCharCode("10003"), //checkmark
    String.fromCharCode(61558) : String.fromCharCode("10070")  //black diamond minus white X
};
```

This object is called from a regular expression to change the characters within a string based on the character codes but currently firebug is throwing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
String.fromCharCode(61607) : String.fromCharCode("9632"),  //solid
```

Comment: That’s not an Array, that’s an object … http://stackoverflow.com/a/19837961/1427878

Comment: FYI, that's a JSON object, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the object to compile, you could do like this instead:

```
var replacementMap = {};

replacementMap[String.fromCharCode(61607)] = String.fromCharCode("9632");  //solid box
replacementMap[String.fromCharCode(61623)] = String.fromCharCode("9679");  //solid circle
replacementMap[String.fromCharCode(61656)] = String.fromCharCode("9654");  //right arrow
replacementMap[String.fromCharCode(61692)] = String.fromCharCode("10003"); //checkmark
replacementMap[String.fromCharCode(61558)] = String.fromCharCode("10070");  //black diamond minus white X
```

But they are right - it's not an array! :)

Comment: Paul Roub was there first though (just for the record)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use function/method calls as object literal keys.  You'll want something like:

```
var replacementMap = {};

replacementMap[ String.fromCharCode(61607) ] = String.fromCharCode("9632");  //solid box
replacementMap[ String.fromCharCode(61623) ] = String.fromCharCode("9679");

// etc.
```