# Alternative to variable keys in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I use a variable value as an object key?

For example, when adding an object dynamically to a Collection. When I to do it like this:

```
addToDB(type, account) {
  Accounts.insert({type: account});
};
```

it doesn't work as the key can't be a variable here.

Comment: for instance? can you give an example of what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript object literal don't support dynamic keys.

Instead you can achieve the goal using :

```
var obj = {};
var key = "some key";
obj[key] = "test";
```

In your case:

```
addToDB(type, account) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[type] = account;
  Accounts.insert(obj);
};
```

More details here:
[Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/javascript-creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: Your answer is not accurate anymore. ES6 adds support for creating dynamic object keys. In case of the question above the answer would be 
`addToDB(type, account) {
  Accounts.insert({[type]: account});
};`
Maybe you could improve your answer?