# jQuery use variable as array key

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var diena = "example"

array.push({diena: sub_array});
```

I want to array key use variable and have key `"example"` not `"diena"`. How I can do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19837916/218196 is the best duplicate since it covers ES6 features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to construct the object beforehand.

```
var diena = "example";
var obj = {};
obj[diena] = sub_array;

array.push(obj);
```