# Define JS object using array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variable-assignment

What's wrong with this? How should I be doing it?

```
var arr = ['image', 'image.jpg'];
var obj = {arr[0]: arr[1]};
```

Comment: [Creating object with dynamic keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/javascript-creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I'm confused by that because of the JQuery complication. Is the salient part the brackets?

Comment: Object initializers expect keys to be literals – strings, numbers, or identifiers (used only for their names). In browsers/engines supporting ES2015, you can use additional brackets to define the key from a variable/expression – `var obj = { [arr[0]]: arr[1] };`. Otherwise, it'll have to be a separate statement – `var obj = {}; obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];`.

Comment: Reference: [MDN: Object Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks. That was what I needed. Want to turn that into an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that expressions like `arr[0]` cannot be used as keys in the [literal initializer notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) of an object. Instead, the property must be assigned dynamically.

```
var arr = ['image', 'image.jpg'];
var obj = {};
obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
```