# Return an Object Key and Value from an Array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this Array, I need to get out each **name** and **age** value, and then make the **name** value a new key and the **age** value a new value.

**The Array**

```
var arr = [
 {name: "jack", age: 32 },
 {name: "jane", age: 34 }
]
```

**My previous code**

```
var monthlyProfit = _.map(arr, function(v) {
  var obj = {
    v.name: v.age
  };

  return obj;
});

console.log(monthlyProfit) // Error
```

**Expectation**

```
var arr = [
 {jack: 32},
 {jane: 34}
]
```

I am using lodash, but vanilla JS won't be a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/javascript-creating-object-with-dynamic-keys might shed some light on why you're code isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're currently trying to define the property will not work. There are multiple ways to achieve what you're trying to achieve, but I'd usually do it like this (using ES5):

```
var monthlyProfit = _.map(arr, function(v) {
  return {[v.name]  : v.age};
});
```

Or like this, as ES6 one-liners:

```
//using lodash
var monthlyProfit = _.map(arr, ({ name, age }) => ({ [name]: age }))

//or, pure ES6 without lodash:
var monthlyProfit = arr.map(({ name, age }) => ({ [name]: age }))
```

You should be seeing `Syntax Error: Unexpected token .` at the line where you're creating the object in your current code.