# How to create JavaScript object with key and value pair dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Actually I am new to JavaScript, How to create JavaScript object with key and value pair dynamically?
I want to create JavaScript object dynamically as mentioned below :-

```
var Categories = {

Education: {

    name: 'Education',
    models: ['Engineering', 'Arts', 'B.com'],

},

Medical: {

    name: 'Medical',
    models: ['Radiologist', 'Surgeon', 'Neurologist'],

},

Agriculture: {

    name: 'Agriculture',
    models: [ ' Domesticated', 'Bee keep', 'Live stock ‎', 'Orchards ‎', 
'Organic farming ‎'],

   },
};
```

Comment: [this might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: Where does the dynamic key/value come in? What have you tried? Have you looked at [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: I Am getting values from two tables category and sub-category and want to show like key value pair suppose I have Education category in category table and Engineering', 'Arts', 'B.com' are the sub-category under Education category.

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid collision with Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for creating json you can use two syntax :

Dot syntax:

```
var obj ={};
obj.someKnowValue = yourThing;
```

Bracket syntax :

```
var x = 'someDynamicString';
var obj = {};
obj[x] = yourThing;
```

So you can achieve it by using 2nd method where you will pass Education and all as variable to be a key.

Comment: thanks for your answer , But I need  like



    Education: {

    name: 'Education',
    models: ['Engineering', 'Arts', 'B.com'],

},

first get Education dynamically then add name and models into particular category.

Comment: `obj.Education.name = "Education"; obj.Education.models = ['Engineering', 'Arts', 'B.com'];` replace the values with your table values.