# Dynamically create query Params in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dynamic, parameters, routes

i want to achieve that the queryParams can be dynmamically passed it. For now i can set the values of the params dynamically, but not the keys

Here is my Code

```
onItemClick(item: FilterItem, group: FilterGroup, i: number) {

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { name : group.items[i].param }
    };
     this.router.navigate(['/search'], navigationExtras);
  }
```

I cannot put instead of "name" my group.name which is a string. I tried this:

```
 queryParams: { group.name: group.items[i].param }
```

But here i get syntax error. How can i put the "key" of a queryParam through an object like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```ts
 queryParams: { [group.name]: group.items[i].param }
```

See also [Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: And what will happen if I `group.name` and `group.items[i].param` come as blank...will it redirect without parameter...I want to make anchor dynamic for different pages which of them would not have parameters..please respond

Comment: Sorry, don't know by heart. Just try it.

Comment: Cant get this to work in the template e.g. `[queryParams]="{[queryField]: queryValue}"`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan hard to tell from this information. I guess it's better to create a new question with more information.

Comment: Was trying to set query params in a `routerLink` in the template where `queryField` and `queryValue` are `@Input`'s. e.g. `<a [routerLink]="someUrlPath" [queryParams]="{[queryField]: queryValue}">`. I had to do it using ngOnInit instead. Was getting template errors

Comment: I guess this is not supported in the template. Assign it to a field in the comonents class and bind to that field.

Comment: how to dynamically add several number of query params?

Comment: queryParams is just an object. Just set the properties amd then pass the object afterwards.