# Define the object literal key from a string variable value

Tags: javascript, typescript

instead of:

```
 sourceFormControl.setErrors({ "scoresGreaterThan": true });
```

I need it dynamic:

```
 let errorKey = "scoresGreaterThan";
 sourceFormControl.setErrors({ errorKey: true });
```

but that did not work :-/

I want the content of the errorKey to be the key of the object literal passed to the setErrors method.

How can I do that with TypeScript?

Comment: `sourceFormControl.setErrors({ [ errorKey ] : true });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the key inside square brackets.

```
sourceFormControl.setErrors({ [errorKey]: true });
```

Comment: just found it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys and it worked, thx!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an object and then assign a value to that key.

```
 let errorKey = "scoresGreaterThan";
 let obj = {};
 obj[errorKey] = true;
 sourceFormControl.setErrors(obj);
```