# What is wrong with this mongo $or query

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

This query works perfectly

```
{
$or:[{author:this.userId} , {somethingelse:true} ]
}
```

But when I try:

```
{
$or:[{author:this.userId} , {sharedwith[this.userId]:true} ]
}
```

I receive the message

> Errors prevented startup:
>          While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.linux.x86_64):    server/main.js:113:43: Unexpected token, expected
>   , (113:43)
>
> => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

And thats where the comma **,** in the $or statement is

Help

Comment: what do you get when you do JSON.stringify of the query just before the execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to retrieve all documents for which the current user is the author, *or* which have been shared with him/her? And therefore that you have structured your documents with a `sharedWith` field which is a hash map of `userId` as keys and `boolean` as value?

Document structure:

```js
{
    author: string,
    sharedWith: {
        <userId1>: boolean
        // <userId2>…
    }
}
```

In that case, your MongoDB query should use the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#field-in-embedded-document-equals-a-value) to specify the value of a nested field within `sharedWith` field:

```js
{
    $or: [{
        author: string
    }, {
        "sharedWith.<userId>": boolean
    }]
}
```

To easily create the query with the interpolated value of `<userId>`, you can use a [*computed key*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys/19837961#19837961) in your object (ES6 syntax):

```js
{
    $or:[{
        author: this.userId
    } , {
        // The query computed key must be in square brackets.
        // Specify the field child key using the dot notation within your query.
        ["sharedwith." + this.userId]: true
    }]
}
```

Or with good old ES5 syntax, similarly to @MichelFloyd's answer:

```js
var query = {
        $or: [{
            author: this.userId
        }]
    };
var newCondition = {};

newCondition["sharedWith." + this.userId] = true;
query.$or.push(newCondition);
```

**Note:** the above described document structure could conveniently replace the `sharedWith` hash map by an array (since having a `false` value for the boolean could simply be replaced by removing the corresponding `userId` from the array):

```js
{
    author: string,
    sharedWith: [
        <userId1>
        // <userId2>…
    ]
}
```

In which case the query would simply [become](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#array-element-equals-a-value):

```js
{
    $or:[{
        author: this.userId
    } , {
        // In MongoDB query, the below selector matches either:
        // - documents where `sharedWith` value is a string equal to
        //     the value of `this.userId`, or
        // - documents where `sharedWith` value is an array which contains
        //     an element with the same value as `this.userId`.
        sharedwith: this.userId
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building the query as a variable before running it.

```
let query = { $or: [{ author: this.userId }]};
const sw = sharedwith[this.userId];
query.$or.push({sw: true});
MyCollection.find(query);
```