# create react state name with variable reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to create state like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    nextProps.columns.forEach((c) => {
      const name = nextProps.columns[nextProps.columns.indexOf(c)];
      this.setState({ `${name}`: (this.props.activeHeaders.indexOf(c) > -1) });
      console.log(`${name}`);
    });
  }
```

I am mapping on my array columns, so each item on the array, i want to set state on them as key, is there a possibe way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possible way?

Yes, but the way you are trying is not correct, instead of calling setState inside loop, first prepare an object with all the key-value, then pass that object to setState.

Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let obj = {};

    nextProps.columns.forEach((c, i) => {
        const name = nextProps.columns[nextProps.columns.indexOf(c)];
        obj[name] = this.props.activeHeaders.indexOf(c) > -1;
    });

    this.setState(obj);
}
```

Didn't get the meaning of this line:

```
const name = nextProps.columns[nextProps.columns.indexOf(c)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. this is a good way to achieve what i wanted to do

Answer (score 2):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    nextProps.columns.forEach((c) => {
      const name = nextProps.columns[nextProps.columns.indexOf(c)];
      this.setState({ [name]: (this.props.activeHeaders.indexOf(c) > -1) });
      console.log(`${name}`);
    });
  }
```

This should do the job

Comment: hmm, is that an array? [name]?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys read this this is how you can add dynamic keys to object in
es6