# how do i generate an object via a for loop?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate an object via a for loop, the problem I am having is that the property name is not being generated instead it is just inserted as the variable name.

Here is an example:

```
for (let key in person) { 
    let obj = {key : person[key] };
    console.log(obj);
}
```

If you run this it prints

```
{ key : "smith" }
```

The desired object would be

```
{ name : "smith" }
```

any ideas on how to achieve this? thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is :

```js
const person = {
  age: 18,
  size: '1m74',
  eyeColor: 'blue',
};

for (let key in person) { 
  const obj = { 
    [key] : person[key],
  };

  console.log(obj);
}
```

---

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys) for explainations

---

---

Example with `Array.forEach` and `Object.keys`

```js
const person = {
  age: 18,
  size: '1m74',
  eyeColor: 'blue',
};

Object.keys(person).forEach((x) => {
  const obj = {
    [x]: person[x],
  };

  console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using

```
for (let key in person) { 
  const obj = {};
  obj[key] = person[key];

  console.log(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by :

```
obj = {name: person[key] }
```

Comment: i will not always be sure off all the properties in the object so hard coding is not an option i am afraid!