# Nodejs and Mongoose render path for $inc query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please help me. I have o problem like this. I have my query :

```
$inc: {
    quantity: -qty,
    saled: qty,
    'colors.2.quantity' :  -qty,
    'size.1.quantity' : -qty 
},
```

The query above work fine. But if i, render path for update color and size like this by Nodejs :

```
let colorPath = `colors.${index}.quantity`;
let sizePath = `size.${index}.quantity`;
```

Then query like this :

```
$inc: {
    quantity: -qty,
    saled: qty,
    colorPath :  -qty,
    sizePath : -qty 
},
```

It does't work. The index of item in colors or size array is not fixed. So, i need to pass like above. How can i do that, please help me... Thanks for your time :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$inc: {
    quantity: -qty,
    saled: qty,
    colorPath :  -qty,
    sizePath : -qty 
},
```

with

```
$inc: {
    quantity: -qty,
    saled: qty,
    [colorPath] : -qty,
    [sizePath] : -qty 
},
```

When you are writing `colorPath` it get interpreted as a string. Using the notation`[]` will tells the interpretor that you are using a variable.

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys?lq=1) an other stack overflow post about dynamical keys.

Comment: Really really thank you... <3 You just save my day, brother !