# Updating with mongoose using dynamic path

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model looks like this:

```
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'eventTitle': String,
    'location': String,
    'startDate': String,
    'endDate': String,
    'startTime': String,
    'endTime': String,
    'createdBy': mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Here we will store the _ID from the user EOSP.
    'attendants': {
        'seekers': [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        'employers': [
        //     {
        //         'id': mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //         'boothVisits': Number,
        //     }
        ],
    },
    'isFinished': {'type': Boolean, 'default': false},
    'uploadedResumes': Number,
    'downloadedResumes': Number,
});
```

And this is my code:

```
Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId, {$inc:{`attendants.employers[${req.params._id}].boothVisits`: 1}, $upsert: true});
```

So the problem is, if I try to do this ^^^^^ my node yells at me saying:

> /home/alex/Documents/Projects/ontario-job-portal/routes/employer.js:58
>       Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId, {$inc: {`attendants.employers[${req.params._id}].boothVisits`: 1}, $upsert: true});
>                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected template string

But if I try to do this:

```
const path = `attendants.employers[${req.params._id}].boothVisits`;
Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId, {$inc: {path: 1}, $upsert: true});
```

My IDE tells me that the `path` variable is actually not used in the query. How can I get around it? I really need the id to be dynamic.

Comment: Try `Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId, {$inc:{attendants.employers.[req.params._id].boothVisits: 1}, $upsert: true});`

Comment: I like the idea, but this tells me `Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId, {$inc:{attendants.employers.[req.params._id].boothVisits: 1}, $upsert: true});
                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: You're looking for creating object with dynamic key. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: @willie17 that was it! Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below query

> Tested on mongo GUI.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


db.getCollection('content')
  .update({
    'attendants.employers.id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId((req.params._id)
    }, {
    $inc: { "attendants.employers.$.boothVisits": 1 }
  })
```

Comment: I see the logic here, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Catch doesn't throw any errors. It just doesn't increment. Any idea why?

Comment: change req.params._id with ObjectId(req.params._id)

Comment: You also use `mongoose ` to convert string into `ObjectId`

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why this works? What is the `$` and why do I need the `mongoose.Types...`?

Comment: `req.params._id` is string and its not match in `mongodb` objectId. So, you need to convert to `ObjectId` to match in mongo

Comment: for `$` you can refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Answer (score 0):

try this?:

```
Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId,
     {
        $inc: { 'attendants.employers.boothVisits': {$in: [req.params._id] }: 1}, 
        $upsert: true
     });
```

Comment: This tells me `/home/alex/Documents/Projects/ontario-job-portal/routes/employer.js:58
    Event.findByIdAndUpdate(eventId, {$inc: { 'attendants.employers.boothVisits': {$in: [req.params._id] }: 1},$upsert: true});
                                                                                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
`