# configure the text label in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to configure the text label user friendly. eg http response be like

```
[
  {
    "approved_datetimestamp": "",
    "approved_by": "",
    "effective_datetimestamp": "",
    "act_datetimestamp": "",
    "expiry_datetimestamp": "",
    "rejected_datetimestamp": "",
    "rejected_by": ""
  }
]
```

Here, the key is a label, I want to configure that key. E.g. `approved_datetimestamp` would be `Approved Datetimestamp`.

I have approach that we can create constant variable like

```
const approved_datetimestamp = "Approved Datetimestamp";
```

when we displaying in template, I am using:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">{{row[rcolumn] | uppercase}}</div>
```

or else 
capitalise first letter of each word and replace underscore with a space. am expacting this

Comment: Do you want to capitalise first letter of each word and replace underscore with a space or...? It's not clear to me what you need this array of object(s) for.

Comment: Yes your idea also good. capitalise first letter of each word and replace underscore with a space. am expacting this

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, iterate through object properties, split them on underscore and capitalise each word, then assign it to the property.

```js
var object = {
    "approved_datetimestamp": "jsjs",
    "approved_by": "",
    "effective_datetimestamp": "",
    "act_datetimestamp": "",
    "expiry_datetimestamp": "",
    "rejected_datetimestamp": "",
    "rejected_by": ""
};

for(var property in object) {
   var newProperty = property.toLowerCase()
                             .split('_')
                             .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
                             .join(' ');
   object[newProperty] = object[property];
   delete object[property];
}

console.log(object);
```

Comment: expected results 
`{
  "Approved Datetimestamp": "",
  "Approved By": "",
}`
Instead of  `{
  "approved_datetimestamp": "Approved Datetimestamp",
  "approved_by": "Approved By"}`

Comment: @Vijay you can create a new object with those keys, instead of properties of existing keys using the same filter

Comment: @AlekseySolovey if put object[key] instead of object[property]

Comment: `for(var property in object) {
  if(object[keys(property)] !=undefined){
   object[keys(property)] = object[keys(property)]
                              .split('_')
                              .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
                              .join(' ');
}
}`

Comment: the above returns the same as it is

Comment: Can you accept the answer if this is what you expected? It will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about creating [*dynamic keys*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

You need to create a key with some filter (*I got the code from* [LazioTibijczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064842/8495123)), then simply pass it into an object to assign it. It will create that new key dynamically. Here is a demo of it:

```js
var object = {
  "approved_datetimestamp": "",
  "approved_by": "",
  "effective_datetimestamp": "",
  "act_datetimestamp": "",
  "expiry_datetimestamp": "",
  "rejected_datetimestamp": "",
  "rejected_by": ""
};

var new_object = {};

for (var property in object) {
  var new_key = property.toLowerCase()
    .split('_')
    .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
    .join(' ');
  new_object[new_key] = "";
}

console.log(new_object);
```