# How to assign javascript variables in a scalable way

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Suppose I have the following `dc.js` objects:

```
var chart_11   = dc.barChart("#chart-11"),
    chart_12   = dc.barChart("#chart-12"),
    chart_13   = dc.barChart("#chart-13"),
    chart_21   = dc.barChart("#chart-21"),
    chart_22   = dc.barChart("#chart-22"),
    chart_23   = dc.barChart("#chart-23");
```

Next, I read in some data and do some stuff with that data:

```
d3.csv("../data/test_data.csv").then(function(data) {

    var var_names = ["x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"];

    var ndx = crossfilter(data),
        chart_11_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[0]]; }),
        chart_12_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[1]]; }),
        chart_13_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[2]]; }),
        chart_21_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[3]]; }),
        chart_22_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[4]]; }),
        chart_23_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[5]]; });

    var chart_11_min = +chart_11_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[0]],
        chart_11_max = +chart_11_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[0]],
        chart_12_min = +chart_12_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[1]],
        chart_12_max = +chart_12_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[1]],
        chart_13_min = +chart_13_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[2]],
        chart_13_max = +chart_13_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[2]],
        chart_21_min = +chart_21_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[3]],
        chart_21_max = +chart_21_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[3]],
        chart_22_min = +chart_22_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[4]],
        chart_22_max = +chart_22_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[4]],
        chart_23_min = +chart_23_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[5]],
        chart_23_max = +chart_23_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[5]];

});
```

While this works, it's not very dry nor is it easy to maintain scale. I know there has to be a better way to dynamically create these variables, but I'm not confident on which approach (e.g. loops, maps, reduce) are likely to scale the best. I do not code frequently in javascript, so I am hoping someone more experienced can point me in the right direction.

Comment: where/how do you use the variables later?

Comment: If you need multiple similar variables, don't create them in the global scope, store them in an `Array`. eg. `const charts =[]; for(let i = 1; i < 3; ++i) chart[i] = db.barChart(\`#chart-${i}\`);` After you have this array it should be easy to deduce the rest of the DRY coding.

Comment: If your variable needs a number, it probably shouldn't be a variable.

Comment: @KevinB Unless it's math: `x1, y1, x2, y2` :D

Comment: nah, `x = [1,2]`

Comment: @NinaScholz these are later used to draw the actual dc.js chart objects: for example: `chart_11
  .dimension(chart_11_dim)
  .group(chart_11_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_11_min - ((chart_11_max - chart_11_min) * breathing_room), chart_11_max + ((chart_11_max - chart_11_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c11_bin; });`

Comment: It's very common in high performance apps (games) to use multiple variables instead of an Object/Array in order to speed-up memory access and reduce garbage created. But I do agree and love your initial statement :D

Comment: I think this kind of questions are more related to a [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: And related to the question itself, you can opt for holding all those variables as properties of an object created dynamically. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837961/2247494) for _"Creating object with dynamic keys"._

After the object has been created you can navigate thought its properties with a `for...in` loop or with `Object.keys(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: @jherax thank you -- I debated code review; perhaps I'll move it there.

Comment: I bet you could clean this up with some judicious use of functions, e.g. make a function that creates a dimension and group and initializes the chart.

Comment: @Gordon - thanks, I moved this to [`Code Review`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215041/48977) with a more complete example.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper file to export the variables as a javascript module.

So in your module file named "data.js" you could have:

```
export const chart11   = dc.barChart("#chart-11"),
    chart12   = dc.barChart("#chart-12"),
    chart13   = dc.barChart("#chart-13"),
    chart21   = dc.barChart("#chart-21"),
    chart22   = dc.barChart("#chart-22"),
    chart23   = dc.barChart("#chart-23");
```

Then wherever you need to reference the data in someotherfile.js you could use:

```
import {chart11, chart12, chart13, chart21, chart22, chart23} from '../data';

const chart11Min = chart11...
```

Idk if you work in node at all, but this is the module pattern used throughout the node environment. This allows a single module declaration and as many import references to that module as needed. Side note, recommend using `const` for constant variables and `let` for dynamic variables. The `var` keyword is not best practice due to its lack of differentiation.