# Clsx - What is and how to use it

Tags: reactjs, jss, class-names

I am trying to understand some uses of clsx in assigning classnames to a component in React.

The construct

```
className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
```

is clear enough. It applies `classes.menuButton`, and also applies `classes.hide` if the value of the boolean `open` is `true`.

My question relates to this second example:

```
className={clsx(classes.appBar, {[classes.appBarShift]: open })}
```

This will apply `classes.appBar`. But what is the meaning of the second parameter?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

`clsx` is generally used to conditionally apply a given `className`

This syntax means that some class will only be applied if a given condition evaluates to `true`

```
const menuStyle = clsx({
    [classes.root] : true, //always applies
    [classes.menuOpen] : open //only when open === true
})
```

In this example `[classes.menuOpen]` (which will evaluate to something like `randomclassName123`) will only be applied if `open === true`

---

`clsx` basically outputs a [string interpolation](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx/blob/master/src/index.js). So you don't have to necessarily use it.

There are many supported syntax that you can check in the official [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx#usage)

Instead of

```
<div className={`${classes.foo} ${classes.bar} ${classes.baz}`} />
```

You can use it like this

```
const { foo, bar, baz } = classes
const style = clsx(foo, bar, baz)

return <div className={style} />
```

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly then 'open && classes.menuOpen' has exactly the same effect as '[classes.menuOpen] : open'.

Comment: Yeap. They are just two different ways to achieve the same result

Comment: Thanks again. Last comment - The construct 'className={clsx(classes.appBar, {[classes.appBarShift]: open })}' would have the same effect as 'className={clsx(classes.appBar, {classes.appBarShift: open})}'. The array is really only needed when there is more than one rule dependent on the value of open.

Comment: Yes. You can check all the possible sintaxes for `clsx` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

Comment: No... the array syntax is for dynamic keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837961/3494249 `{classes.appBarShift: open}` would cause an error; `{[classes.appBarShift]: open}` would create an object with the value of  `classes.appBarShift` as a key.

Comment: He is refering to pass an array of classes to `clsx`. Dynamic keys don't have anything to do with that. Yes his example code will fail for the lack of `[]` delimiting the key. But that wasn't his question

Answer (score 34):

Many people already explained it pretty well. I still wanted to add an example containing className. In the example you can see different classes, applied if a given condition evaluates to true. In the example you can apply a class with a boolean value, a boolean variable or a compared string (If match, return true).
The class `classes.drawer` is always applied and does not depend on a condition.

```
className={clsx(classes.drawer, {                  // classes.drawer is applied always
          [classes.drawerOpen]: true,              // classes.drawerOpen is applied always, bool = true
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,            // you can also use boolean variable
          [classes.drawerRed]: colorVar === 'red', // you can also use string variable
        })}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explaination to your code? [Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Answer (score 2):

`classes.appBarShift` will be applied only if `open` evaluates to `true`. If the array has more classes all of them will be applied if `open` evaluates to `true`