# Conditionally setting className based on a state variable in a React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, classname, use-state

I'm trying to change the appearance of a button based on if that element exists in state. It is a multiple selection selection. So setAnswer is called, which calls addAnswer. I then want to set the className based on whether the element is in state but I'm just not getting it.

```
{question.values.map(answer => {
        return  <button className="buttons" key={answer} onClick={() => addAnswer(answer)}>
        {answer}</button>
})}
```

```
const addAnswer = (answer) => {
        let indexAnswer = answers.indexOf(answer)
        if (indexAnswer > -1) {
            setAnswer((answers) => answers.filter((a) => { 
                return a != answer }))}

        else setAnswer([...answers, answer])
    };
```

Comment: I would like to suggest that perhaps you have an id for your question, it just might make it easier to look them up, select them and do comparisons,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can conditionally set a class like this

```js
{question.values.map(answer => {
        return (<button 
                 className={answers.indexOf(answer) === -1 ? 'class1' : 'class2'} 
                 key={answer} 
                 onClick={() => addAnswer(answer)}
               >
                 {answer}
              </button> );
})}
```

Comment: Thank you Siddharth!

Answer (score 5):

clsx is the perfect candidate for this. You can conditionaly set one or more classNames which get used if a condition is true.

Here's a real working snippet I made which is also available here https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sound-2d5fr?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import clsx from "clsx";

import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

// Create your Styles. Remember, since React-JSS uses the default preset,
// most plugins are available without further configuration needed.
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  answer1: { color: "red" },
  answer2: { color: "green" },
  answer3: { color: "yellow" }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const questions = {
    values: [
      { type: 1, value: "aaaa" },
      { type: 2, value: "bbbb" },
      { type: 3, value: "cccc" },
      { type: 1, value: "dddd" },
      { type: 2, value: "eeee" },
      { type: 3, value: "ffff" }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {questions.values.map(answer => (
        <p>
          <button
            className={clsx(classes.always, {
              [classes.answer1]: answer.type === 1,
              [classes.answer2]: answer.type === 2,
              [classes.answer3]: answer.type === 3
            })}
          >
            {answer.value}
          </button>
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

for more information on clsx see this example here [Understanding usage of clsx in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557271/understanding-usage-of-clsx-in-react)

Alternatively you can determine the class name via logic and set it in a variable like this

```
const getClassName = ()=> { 

  switch(answer) {
    case(1): return "class1"
    case(2): return "class2"
    ...
  }
   
}

render(
  /// within the map function
  <   className={getClassName()}  />
)
```