# Passing an object property through a variable in spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have done this before in a react project.

```js
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({ username: '', password: '', });

const handleInputChange = (e)=>{
    if(e.target.name==="username"){
        setFormState({...formState, username:e.target.value })
    }
    if(e.target.name==="password"){
        setFormState({...formState, password:e.target.value })
        }
    }
```

My two input elements had the onChange={handleInputChange} to update input value.

Now I have a form that has numerous inputs. And I want a code that can update the input based on the input name. something like this.

```js
const handleInputChange=(e)=>{
    const inputName = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setFormState({...formState, inputName:value })
   };
```

I need help on that please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put inputName inside [ ]

```
const handleInputChange=(e)=>{
    const inputName = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setFormState({...formState, [inputName]:value })
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

ES2015 allows you to create a computed property name on an object by using the following syntax:

```
const a = { [someKeyName]: 'myValue' }
```

so you could write:

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
};
```

There is a great answer dealing with this here: [Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

It also notes to take care when considering where this syntax will be used. Make sure it is supported in the browsers you intend to support. According to the [MDN docs here,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) it wouldn't be usable in IE unless transpiled.

Answer (score 0):

You can make input name dynamic like this

```
const handleInputChange=(e)=>{
  const inputName = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  setFormState({...formState, [inputName]:value })
};
```