# Creating modified array from array's objects not possible with dot-notation as key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why can I not set a `key` in a newly created object like this:

```
const baseObject = {key: "a", val: "b"}
const modifiedObject = {baseObject.val: baseObject.key} // SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

But instead using brackets is ok:

```
const modifiedObject = {[baseObject.val]: baseObject.key} // OK
```

From my understanding `[baseObject.val]` should create a new array from the `baseObject.val` with only that item in it. Can you explain why this works? Is this the best practice approach on setting a `key` from an object's nested property?

I tried finding information on MDN and other sources but could not find any.
I assume my search phrases are wrong since there should be a pretty basic explanation.
Feel free to mark as duplicate if you can link me to already provided answers.

Comment: Also see [*How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal) and [*Creating object with dynamic keys*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have with `[baseObject.val]` is not an array, but a ["computed property name"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), a special syntax for object literals.

What it does is, when inside an object literal where a key should be, it evaluates the expression inside the brackets and then defines a property on the object being constructed with that expression. For example, `{ ['foo']: 'bar' }` results in `{ foo: 'bar' }`. `{ ['a' + 'b']: 'bar' }` results in `{ ab: 'bar' }`.

You can put any expression you want inside the `[]` brackets, and the result will be the key put on the object. For your case, you want the expression value of `baseObject.val`, so the syntax is `[baseObject.val]:`.

Comment: Can you also explain why the notation without brackets is not allowed in JavaScript? I don't see the reason why...

Comment: I would guess that it's because otherwise, the interpreter would have to dynamically determine whether what was referenced was an expression or was meant to be a plain string property, eg `const foo = 'abc'; const obj = { foo: 'val' }`. Would the object be `{ foo: 'val' }` or `{ abc: 'val' }`? Rules could be made to determine it, but it'd be confusing for script-writers and would complicate the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

`[` and `]` are punctuators that have a different meaning in different contexts. Depending on where they appear, they might signify an array literal:

```
let a = [];
```

or delimit a property name (aka "square bracket notation") where an expression is to be evaluated to get the property name:

```
let foo = 'log';
console[foo]('foo'); // equivalent to console.log('foo');
```

or define assignment of array values to variables:

```
let [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]
```

In the context of the OP, they delimit a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Description), similar to the second example above:

```
let x = 'foo';
let obj= {[x] : 'Foo'};
```

which creates an object as if by:

```
let obj = {foo: 'Foo'};
```