# Updating state for a value inside an object immutably in redux reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I want to update a state value where the key is also dynamic in redux reducer, but I tried various method I am not able to do it.

So my **Initial State** looks like this

```
const initalState = {
ingredients:{
  bacon:0,
  salad:0,
  cheese:0,
  meat:0,
},
price:100
};
```

And my data passed in reducer looks like this

```
{type: "INCREASEQUANTITY", payload: {
item: "bacon",
value: 1
}}
```

And I want result state looks like

```
const initalState = {
ingredients:{
  bacon:1, //updated value
  salad:0,
  cheese:0,
  meat:0,
},
price:100
};
```

I tried to update it immutably, but its showing syntax error.
My code for this looks like this

```
      return{
    ...state,
    state.ingredients:{
      ...state.ingredients,
      action.payload.item:state.ingredients[action.payload.item]+action.payload.value //this line explained below
    }
  }
```

I want to update it with key and value both dynamically like `bacon:0+1` but getting syntax issue.

Please help.Thank you

Comment: Use [ ] notation for key. Like this      `[action.payload.item]:state.ingredients[action.payload.item]+action.payload.value`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: @SubinSebastian I tried this also but, it is still showing syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track

```
return {
  ...state,
  ingridients: {
     ...state.ingridients,
     [action.payload.item]: state.ingredients[action.payload.item] + action.payload.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution worked for me. Thanks. I just want to ask `ingredients` here you don't add state but here `[action.payload.item]: state.ingredients[action.payload.item] + action.payload.value` we use `state.ingredients`

Comment: because you are returning a new object, and you need to define its new structure, but in order to not break anything - we define the same structure as in the `initialState`. So if it's was an object on initial, we need to make it an object now too