# Why myObj not recognized from new object

Tags: javascript

Why myObj  not recognized from new object.

I just want my object get myValue as key how can I implement it?

my object

```
let myObj = {
  0: 'adi',
  1: 'itzik'
}

const myValue=4;
myObj = { ...myObj, ...{ myValue: 'dani' } };
```

after code above

my object

```
let myObj = {
  0: 'adi',
  1: 'itzik',
  myValue: 'dani' // should be 4:4
}
```

Comment: `{ myValue: 'dani' }` creates an object with a key of `"myValue"`. If you want to use the *contents* of `myValue` as the key it'd be `{ [myValue]: 'dani' }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed property name.

```js
let myObj = {
  0: 'adi',
  1: 'itzik'
}
const myValue = 4;
myObj = { ...myObj, ...{[myValue]: myValue}};
console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: There are already [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024066/6243352) [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837961/6243352) for this. Why not suggest one to avoid reinventing whole threads of knowledge?

Comment: Thanks it work, but why we need it ? []

Comment: @LichayTiram Using square brackets will set the property name as the value of the expression instead of the literal name `'myValue'`. See [this](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript).