# Use a variable for object name to be changed with spread operator (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to reactjs and javascript, so I'm not sure of the right syntax.

I want to use the spread operator to update an object but instead of hardcoding the field name I want it to be a variable, but it reads it as a field name instead of taking the variable value as the field name.

For example,
This is my variable:

```
let [obj, setObj] = useState({'title': '', 'body': ''})
```

I update it like this:

```
const onChangeCallBack(field, value){
   if(field === 'body'){
       setObj(obj => ({...obj, 'body': value}))
   }else if(field === 'title'){
       setObj(obj => ({...obj, 'title': value}))
   }
}
```

I want to update something like this instead:

```
const onChangeCallBack(field, value){
   setObj(obj => ({...obj, field: value})) // This doesn't work
   setObj(obj => ({...obj, {field}: value})) // This doesn't work either
}
```

So is there a way to specify that the field is a variable to take it's value as the variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
setObj(obj => ({...obj, [field]: value}))
```

Use square brackets to use dynamic keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap dynamic keys with square braquets like so:

```
{ [myDynamicKey]: value }
```

More on the subject here: [Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)