# Define object field name based on variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is possible in javascript define an object field name based on the value of a variable INLINE?

for exemple:

```
const field = "name";

const js = {field:"rafael"};

console.log(js);
```

the result of this code will be `{field:rafael}` but the result I want is `{name:rafael}`.

I know I can do

```
const field = "name";

const js = {};
js[field] = "rafael";
```

but i would like to do inline as I initialize the object. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use a dynamic key: `{ [field]: 'rafael' }`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: I'm sorry it is a repeated question, I tried to search before but i wast'n really good into resume the question in one sentence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The es6 version of JavaScript allows you to handle this issue, we can use variables while creating the object to dynamically set the property like so:

```js
const field = "name";

const js = {[field] : "rafael"};

console.log(js);
```

Setting dynamic property keys - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-set-dynamic-javascript-object-property-keys-with-es6