# Dynamically creating array of objects with dynamic key values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array of objects from the sample response received as `const val` with dynamic keys and values. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837949/11156131) which helped me with dynamic key columns; but I am unable to dynamically assign the values to the keys.

`const key` is dynamic and val.dims would always contain the exact same number of objects as the number of values in key. If key has 3 candidates; val would contain 3 objects.

I don't want to achieve this by hardcoding if possible.

```js
const val = {
    "dims": [{
            "flOne": {},
            "values": [
                100,
                99,
                98,
                97,
                96              
            ]
        },
        {
            "flOne": {},
            "values": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
            ]
        }
    ]
};


const keys = ['a', 'b'];
const lenOne = keys.length;
const base = val.dims[0].values;
const lenTwo = base.length;

console.log(lenOne, lenTwo);

const data = [];
let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < lenTwo; i++) {
    const vals = base
    keys.forEach(
        (a, j) => {
            obj[a] = vals[i];
            return obj;
        }
    )
    data.push(obj);
}

console.log(data);
```

I desire this
`[{ a: 1, b:100 }, { a: 2, b: 99 }, { a: 3, b: 98 }, { a: 4, b: 97 }, { a: 5, b: 96 }]`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, using `reduce` is what comes to mind:

```js
const val = {
  "dims": [{
      "flOne": {},
      "values": [
        100,
        99,
        98,
        97,
        96
      ]
    },
    {
      "flOne": {},
      "values": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
      ]
    }
  ]
};


const keys = ['a', 'b'];
const base = val.dims[0].values;

const data = base.map((_, idx) => (
  keys.reduce((acc, curr, i) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr]: val.dims[i].values[idx]
  }), {})
))

console.log(data)
```

Comment: small thing is that a and b have to be switched but that can also be achieved by switching the keys

Comment: @cmgchess well OP said that number of keys can be dynamic "If key has 3 candidates...", OP didn't say in what order it would be if it's more than 2, so I just assumed the expected output OP wrote was not in the correct order. But let's see what OP would respond to this

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and for loop to achieve this

```js
const val = {
    "dims": [{
            "flOne": {},
            "values": [
                100,
                99,
                98,
                97,
                96              
            ]
        },
        {
            "flOne": {},
            "values": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
            ]
        }
    ]
};


const keys = ['a', 'b'];
const result = [];
for(let i=0; i < keys.length; i ++){
   val.dims[i].values.map((item, index) => {
    if(result[index]){
        result[index][keys[i]] = item
    }
    else {
        result[index] = {
            [keys[i]]: item
        }
    }
})
}

console.log(result);
```